# Rails date format in text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

1. If i let the user to type the date_format in text_field. is there any format to validate the date_format if the user enters invalid string?
2. If i show the date_formats as drop downs, Is there any international date_formats available?

eg: Date-formats (MMM. d, YYYY),(h:mm a)

Any Suggestions.

Comment: best way is use a jquery datepicker, u can customize the date format.

Comment: With HTML5 you can use `<input type="date">` (datetime/datetime-local) which works ok and is localized by your browser.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `Date.parse`? Could be used in both of your questions.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse

Comment: This should be a comment.